# Can I use Azure PIM externally?

Tags: azure, active-directory, pim

I have my company's user directory in azure and manage it through Azure privileged identity management. I wanted to know whether I can integrate this PIM solution with external resources or applications like Cloud providers like Digital ocean.

Answer (score 0):

Azure PIM is to manage and control only resources in Azure AD , Microsoft 365 and Microsoft Intune. You cannot Integrate with external cloud providers like Digital Ocean.